# Python 3.9 - Trying to install module via PIP -> Could not build wheels for tokenizers which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python

I'm simply trying to install the `flair` package using Pip. However nothing I try works and I can't get past the `Could not build wheels for tokenizers which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly` error.

I have the Rust compiler and C++ Build tools installed as I've seen suggested. I've tried installing via `pip3`, I've tried Python versions 3.6 and 3.9.

```
  error[E0603]: module `export` is private
     --> tokenizers-lib\src\tokenizer\mod.rs:24:12
      |
  24  | use serde::export::Formatter;
      |            ^^^^^^ private module
      |
  note: the module `export` is defined here
     --> C:\Users\Jake\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\serde-1.0.123\src\lib.rs:275:5
      |
  275 | use self::__private as export;
      |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried installing `transformers` which is a dependency of `flair` first via `pip3 install transformers==2.4.1` and then trying to install flair.

I've even tried installing via Pycharm's build in installer, that doesn't work either.

Nothing works.

Someone please help me because it's slightly ridiculous that it's this hard to install a package in Python.

Comment: Where is `pip3` pointing? is `pip3 -V` outputting the same python that you expect it to install to?

Comment: I'm getting `pip 21.0.1 from -snip- (python 3.6)`, 3.6 is my current venv version